# Implement autofac in boostrapper (caliburn.micro) correctly

Tags: c#, mvvm, autofac, caliburn.micro

I would like to re-code my first little C# project using Caliburn.Micro and the bootstrapper stuff. During my first approach I used Autofac but now I'm stuck. Without Caliburn I was able to retrieve my employees from a db file like this (mind the scope.resolve stuff -- thats my problem right now):

```
public ObservableCollection<EmployeeEntity> Employees
{
    get
    {
        var container = ContainerConfig.Configure();
        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var test = scope.Resolve<IEmployeeRepository>();
            _Employees = test.GetAll().ToObservable();
        }
        return _Employees;
    }
    set
    {
        _Employees = value;
    }
}
```

Now I switched to Caliburn.Micro incl. bootstrapper which looks like this (I would like to keep the LifeTimeScope stuff)

```
protected override void Configure()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterType<WindowManager>()
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .SingleInstance();

    builder.RegisterType<EventAggregator>()
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .SingleInstance();

    builder.RegisterType<CalendarViewModel>()
        .SingleInstance();

    builder.RegisterType<EmployeeViewModel>()
        .SingleInstance();

    builder.RegisterType<EmployeeRepository>().As<IEmployeeRepository>()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    Container = builder.Build();
}
```

On application start I open "CalendarViewModel" and get the corresponding view. My view contains a menu which opens a second view "EmployeeViewModel" on click with the following implementation:

```
private readonly IWindowManager _windowManager;
public CalendarViewModel(IWindowManager WindowManager)
{
    _windowManager = WindowManager;
}
public void OpenEmployeeView() => _windowManager.ShowWindow(new EmployeeViewModel());
```

Now my problem is how to change and include the code from the beginning (Autofac only) to a working one using the bootstrapper and the implementation of "IEmployeeRepository" with "Lifetimescope".

**What I have tried:**

I tried to include "IEmployeeRepository" like I did with the WindowManager:

```
private ObservableCollection<EmployeeEntity> _Employees;
private readonly IEmployeeRepository _emp;
public EmployeeViewModel(IEmployeeRepository Emp)
{
    _emp = Emp;
}
public ObservableCollection<EmployeeEntity> Employees
{
    get
    {
        _Employees = _emp.GetAll().ToObservable();
        return _Employees;
    }
    set
    {
        _Employees = value;
    }
}
```

but (as you might already know) I get an error

```
CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter
```

So how do I implement Autofac within Bootstrapper correctly? Quite sure that my way isn't the proper way to do it :/

Quick summary:
(bootstrapper) --application start--> (CalendarViewModel) --menu item--> (EmployeeViewModel)

**UPDATE 29.10.2019**:
The line

```
public EmployeeViewModel(IEmployeeRepository Emp)
{
    _emp = Emp;
}
```

throws an error. I guess because my OpenCommand

```
public void OpenEmployeeView() => _windowManager.ShowWindow(new EmployeeViewModel());
```

does not pass any IEmployeeRepository to my EmployeeViewModel.

**UPDATE 29.10.2019 No 2**:
new error message

> System.InvalidOperationException: "A parameterless default constructor
>   or one matching signature (System.Int64 Id, System.String FirstName)
>   is required for Calendar.Database.Entities.EmployeeEntity
>   materialization"

is thrown within 
SqlRepository.cs (GetAll return row throws the error)

```
protected SqlRepository(IDbContext dbContext)
{
    DbContext = dbContext;
}

public IList<TEntity> GetAll()
{
    return DbContext.Connection.GetAll<TEntity>().ToList();
}
```

What I did:
Bootstrapper.cs

```
builder.RegisterType<EmployeeViewModel>()
.SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<DbContext>().As<IDbContext>()
.InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<EmployeeRepository>().As<IEmployeeRepository>()
.InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

CalendarViewModel.cs

```
public void OpenEmployeeView() => _windowManager.ShowWindow(IoC.Get<EmployeeViewModel>());
```

EmployeeViewModel.cs

```
private readonly IEmployeeRepository _emp;
public EmployeeViewModel(IEmployeeRepository Emp)
{
    _emp = Emp;
}
public ObservableCollection<EmployeeEntity> Employees
{
    get
    {
        _Employees = _emp.GetAll().ToObservable();
        return _Employees;
    }
    set
    {
        _Employees = value;
    }
}
```

(I could post a link to my Visual Studio Project … but don't know if it is allowed here)

Comment: Which line causes an error? You can also have a look at [sample](https://gist.github.com/dbuksbaum/11ce61ec4926182a1d01) and try to implement everything according him

Comment: (updated my initial question) I did take a look at the sample and my IWindowManager is working as intended. My guess is that I have to pass an instance of the IEmployeeRepository within my "_windowsManager.ShowWindow" command. For me it does not make any sense to define an IEmployeeRepository within the CalendarViewModel, pass it to the open command and use it within the new window (I already defined it within the bootstrapper :) .. so I really need some help implementing it correctly, not quick and dirty

Comment: @Pavel
found the problem …. had stupid inheritance deep within my entity class -.- Your proposed solution worked

Comment: It's fine, I can undelete my answer and you can vote it as helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use

```cs
var employeeViewModel = IoC.Get<EmployeeViewModel>();
…
public void OpenEmployeeView() => _windowManager.ShowWindow(employeeViewModel);
```

to get instance of `EmployeeViewModel` with injected constructor parameters.

Another option is inject the `EmployeeViewModel` to `CalendarViewModel`, if it fits your arhitecture design

Comment: okay, implemented your suggestion and it seems I missed something else. Get an error "DependencyResolutionException: Unable to resolve the type 'Calendar.Database.DbContext.DbContext' because the lifetime scope it belongs in can't be located. The following services are exposed by this registration:
- Calendar.Database.DbContext.IDbContext". The implementation for IDbContext looks like this  `builder.RegisterType<DbContext>().As<IDbContext>()
                .InstancePerRequest();` Any idea?

Comment: Please, update your question with this details as well, You can also change `InstancePerRequest()` for `IDbContext` to `InstancePerLifetimeScope()` according to autofac [docs](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html)

Comment: Updated my initial post. 
Many thanks for your patience and help!!